# sqlserver merge query cannot access the id values in identity column

Tags: sql-server

Following 5 tables which primary key are level ids. In userlevel1 table primary key was Level1ID and UserLevel2 table primary key is Level2ID it links with UserLevel1 table with a foreign key. Same structure User level3,level4,level5

```
CREATE TABLE [tdm].[UserLevel1](
[UserID] [int],
[Level1ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[USerID] [int] NOT NULL,
[LevelName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[GeoCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[IsDeleted] [bit] NULL
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE [tdm].[UserLevel2](
[Level2ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Level1ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[LevelName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[GeoCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[IsDeleted] [bit] NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [tdm].[UserLevel3](
[Level3ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Level2ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[LevelName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[GeoCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[IsDeleted] [bit] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [tdm].[UserLevel4](
[Level4ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Level3ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[LevelName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[GeoCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[IsDeleted] [bit] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [tdm].[UserLevel5](
[Level5ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Level4ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[LevelName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[GeoCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[IsDeleted] [bit] NULL
)
```

For insert or update to above tables I have use the MERGE Query for each table. Following code contains for level 3 table

```
MERGE INTO tdm.CustomerLevel3 AS [Target]
             USING @TempCustomerLevel3 AS [Source]
             ON [Source].LevelID = [Target].Level3ID 
             WHEN NOT MATCHED 
                AND [Source].[GeoCode]<>'' 
                AND [Source].[LevelName]<>'' 
             THEN
             INSERT
             (
                 [Level2ID]
                ,[LevelName]
                ,[GeoCode]
                ,[IsDeleted]
             )
             VALUES
             (
                  [Source].[ParentLevelID]
                 ,[Source].[LevelName]
                 ,[Source].[GeoCode]
                 ,[Source].[IsDeleted]
             )
             WHEN MATCHED 
             THEN
             UPDATE SET         
                [Level2ID]=[Source].[ParentLevelID]
                ,[LevelName] = [Source].[LevelName]
                ,[GeographyCode] = [Source].[GeographyCode]
                ,[IsDeleted]=IIF([Source].[GeographyCode]<>'' AND [Source].[LevelName]<>'',[Source].[IsDeleted],1);
```

I wrote 5 merge queries for each level tables.Level 1 table and level 2 can manage because it has UserID so that I can join the tables and take the parent id value, but for other tables when inserting I don’t have  level id to make link with other table currently I link through the GeoCode which insert the duplicate values for table.

Comment: How is `@TempCustomerLevel3` populated?

Comment: Its udt same fields which define as above tables

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Your question is currently unanswerable.. you have not provided enough information for anyone to help you.  https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/